# Returning async callback value through function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, google-distancematrix-api

We are using "Google Maps Distance Matrix API"  to calculate the distance(https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro)
The distance matrix API takes the  request and the response is returned via async call back function. In our requirement we want to use the distance value for further processing .Our plan is to build the function which will take the points as input and return  the distance between the points  so that we can use that value for further processing. Since the API returns the result/response in aync callback function we are not able to return the result value from function which we build.
Is there any way workaround to achieve the above mentioned requirement?

Thank You,

Comment: There is no way. You need to make the function you build accept a callback so that you can pass THAT callback to the API function. Or you can use promises which is another type of callback.

Comment: Or put another way, you have a callback that is called when the API has data ready for you. That callback can call any other functions. Put your "further processing" in a function that is called from this callback, or in the callback itself.

Comment: At this point, many people are tempted to think, "since I can't return the data, what if the callback just stores it in a global variable for the other processing code to use?" You could do that, but it doesn't help. How does your other processing code know when the data is ready? You have to signal it somehow, and the way to do that is by calling that code from the callback and passing it the data as a function parameter.